# Android even vertical spacing between widgets

Tags: android, android-layout, android-widget, android-xml

I have a fragment layout that looks like this:

[image]

The top 3 rows are spaced nicely, but the age and sex rows are too short vertically. If I were to hard code a vertical size for the entire layout, is there a way to ensure every item is evenly spaced vertically? Currently, due to the different widget types being used, the bottom too dont look very nice

Here is the code for my layout:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:padding="20dp">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal" >

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="0.4"
            android:text="Research Assistant:" />

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/input_ra"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="0.6"
            android:ems="10"
            android:inputType="textCapWords"/>
    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal" >

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="0.4"
            android:text="Subject Number:" />

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/input_subnum"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="0.6"
            android:ems="10"
            android:inputType="text"/>
    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal" >

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="0.4"
            android:text="Condition:" />

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/input_condition"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="0.6"
            android:ems="10"
            android:inputType="number"/>
    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal" >

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="0.4"
            android:text="Age:" />

        <Spinner
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/input_age_spinner"
            android:layout_weight="0.6" />

    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal" >

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="0.4"
            android:text="Sex:" />

        <RadioGroup
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="0.6"
            android:orientation="horizontal">

            <RadioButton
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="Male"
                android:id="@+id/input_button_male"
                android:paddingRight="10dp"/>

            <RadioButton
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="Female"
                android:id="@+id/input_button_female"
                android:paddingRight="10dp"/>
        </RadioGroup>

    </LinearLayout>


    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:paddingTop="50dp">

        <View
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="0.25" />

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="0.75"
            android:orientation="horizontal" >

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/input_submit"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:ems="5"
                android:text="Save" />

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/input_reset"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:ems="5"
                android:text="Reset" />
        </LinearLayout>
    </LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Perhaps you could consider using `weightSum` and `weight` attribute to evenly distribute it.

Below is the edited code based on that. Noted your `height` would be now `0dp`, and I give more weight to the last buttons.

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:weightSum="10"
    android:padding="20dp">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:orientation="horizontal" >

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="0.4"
            android:text="Research Assistant:" />

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/input_ra"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="0.6"
            android:ems="10"
            android:inputType="textCapWords"/>
    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:orientation="horizontal" >

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="0.4"
            android:text="Subject Number:" />

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/input_subnum"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="0.6"
            android:ems="10"
            android:inputType="text"/>
    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:orientation="horizontal" >

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="0.4"
            android:text="Condition:" />

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/input_condition"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="0.6"
            android:ems="10"
            android:inputType="number"/>
    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:orientation="horizontal" >

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="0.4"
            android:text="Age:" />

        <Spinner
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/input_age_spinner"
            android:layout_weight="0.6" />

    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:orientation="horizontal" >

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="0.4"
            android:text="Sex:" />

        <RadioGroup
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="0.6"
            android:orientation="horizontal">

            <RadioButton
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="Male"
                android:id="@+id/input_button_male"
                android:paddingRight="10dp"/>

            <RadioButton
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="Female"
                android:id="@+id/input_button_female"
                android:paddingRight="10dp"/>
        </RadioGroup>

    </LinearLayout>


    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="5"
        android:paddingTop="50dp"
        android:orientation="horizontal">

        <View
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="0.25" />

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="0.75"
            android:orientation="horizontal" >

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/input_submit"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:ems="5"
                android:text="Save" />

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/input_reset"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:ems="5"
                android:text="Reset" />
        </LinearLayout>
    </LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this. Each row view is equally apart from each other.

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:padding="20dp"
    android:weightSum="12"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:layout_weight="2" >

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="0.4"
            android:text="Research Assistant:" />

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/input_ra"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="0.6"
            android:textAppearance="@android:style/TextAppearance.Medium"
            android:ems="10"
            android:inputType="textCapWords"/>
    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:layout_weight="2"
        android:weightSum="1" >

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="0.4"
            android:text="Subject Number:" />

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/input_subnum"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="0.6"
            android:ems="10"
            android:inputType="text"/>
    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:layout_weight="2"
        android:weightSum="1" >

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="0.4"
            android:text="Condition:" />

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/input_condition"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="0.6"
            android:ems="10"
            android:inputType="number"/>
    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:layout_weight="2"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:weightSum="1" >

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="0.4"
            android:text="Age:" />

        <Spinner
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/input_age_spinner"
            android:layout_weight="0.6" />

    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:layout_weight="2"
        android:weightSum="1" >

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="0.4"
            android:text="Sex:" />

        <RadioGroup
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="0.6"
            android:orientation="horizontal">

            <RadioButton
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="Male"
                android:id="@+id/input_button_male"
                android:paddingRight="10dp"/>

            <RadioButton
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="Female"
                android:id="@+id/input_button_female"
                android:paddingRight="10dp"/>
        </RadioGroup>

    </LinearLayout>


    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:layout_weight="2"
        android:weightSum="1">

        <View
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="0.25" />

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:layout_weight="0.75"
            android:orientation="horizontal" >

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/input_submit"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:ems="5"
                android:text="Save" />

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/input_reset"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:ems="5"
                android:text="Reset" />
        </LinearLayout>
    </LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

Hope this works for you.